# ¿Como puedo hacer que mi aplicacion pida todos los permisos en el MainActivity?

Tags: android

Quiero pedir todos los permisos una sola vez para facilitarme el trabjao es posible?

Estos son mis permisos

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ¿Quiero pedir todos los permisos una sola vez para facilitarme el
>   trabajo es posible?

**Es posible pero no recomendable.**

**No es necesario agregar todos los permisos si no son requeridos por tu aplicación**, si los agregas esto implicaría que cuando el usuario instale tu aplicación, se muestré una lista enorme de permisos los cuales posiblemente el usuario opte por no aceptarlos.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La petición manual de los permisos se realiza en dispositivos Android 6.0 y superior, pero es importante saber que **la petición manual debe realizarse para los [permisos riesgosos](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/security/permissions.html#normal-dangerous) y no para todos los permisos.**

> Los [permisos riesgosos](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/security/permissions.html#normal-dangerous) abarcan áreas en las cuales la app requiere
>   datos o recursos que incluyen información privada del usuario, o bien
>   que podrían afectar los datos almacenados del usuario o el
>   funcionamiento de otras apps. Por ejemplo, la capacidad de leer los
>   contactos del usuario es un permiso riesgoso. Si una app declara que
>   necesita un permiso riesgoso, el usuario tiene que otorgarle
>   explícitamente el permiso.

Los permisos considerados como riesgosos son:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si deseas saber como realizar petición de permisos manual, en el sitio se encuentran varios ejemplos:

[**Android petición manual de permisos.**](https://es.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bandroid%5D%20permisos)

Comment: **CP Cuando se califique con -1, es bueno para el sitio se indique la razón**, esto para mejorar la pregunta, eliminarla o si existen argumentos platicar sobre el tema.

Answer (score 0):

> Respuesta Original [Solicitar permisos en el MainActivity?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42942108/8933039)

Agregue estas líneas para verificar permisos multiples en su código:

```
public static final int MULTIPLE_PERMISSIONS = 100;

// función para verificar permisos
    private void checkPermission() {
    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(),
            Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO) + ContextCompat
            .checkSelfPermission(getActivity(),
                    Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE))
            != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

        if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale
                (getActivity(), Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO) ||
                ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale
                        (getActivity(), Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)) {
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
                requestPermissions(
                        new String[]{Manifest.permission
                                .RECORD_AUDIO, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},
                        MULTIPLE_PERMISSIONS);
            }

        } else {
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
                requestPermissions(
                        new String[]{Manifest.permission
                                .RECORD_AUDIO, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},
                        MULTIPLE_PERMISSIONS);
            }
        }
    } else {
        //pon tu función aquí

    }
}


 //Función para iniciar después de que los permisos sean dados por el usuario
@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode,
                                       String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {

    switch (requestCode) {
        case MULTIPLE_PERMISSIONS:
            if (grantResults.length > 0) {
                boolean recordPermission = grantResults[1] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED;
                boolean writeExternalFile = grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED;
                if(recordPermission && writeExternalFile)
                {
                    // Coloca tu funcion aqui
                }
            }
            else {
                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
                    requestPermissions(
                            new String[]{Manifest.permission
                                    .WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO},
                            MULTIPLE_PERMISSIONS);
                }
            }

    }
}
```

> También puedes ver : [Manifest.permission](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html) todos los permisos necesarios para una aplicación.

**Información adicional** (Traducir del Inglés):

> - [Permiso de verificación de Android antes Main activity](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42118828/8933039)
> - [Comience la actividad después de múltiples permisos? Android 6+](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42687225/8933039)